# Файл базы данных не обновляется в папке bin

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

Использую EFCore с SQLite. Конфигурирующий метод выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class DatabaseModel : DbContext
{
 //...
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Clients.db");
}
```

В процессе изменения модели и применения миграций  возникали ошибки типа "не найдена таблица TableName". Как оказалось visual studio создала 2 файла `clients.db` один в корневой папке, другой в папке bin/Debug/net5.0-windows. Изменения базы данных записываются в файл в корневой папке, а при запуске программы используется тот, который в bin папке. При ручном копировании файла из одного места в другое все работает. Как поменять настойки entity framework, либо visual studio чтобы они ссылались на один и тот же файл базы данных? Я понимаю, что можно прописать путь `bin/Debug/net5.0-windows` вручную, но мне кажется это не совсем верно, т.к. программа не должна знать пути к директориям, которые создает визуал студио.

P.S. Вопрос решился изменением настройки файла базы данных "Копировать в выходной каталог" с "не копировать" на "копировать более поздний файл" как указано на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, сработает такой способ. Копию базы положить в корень проекта, там EF будет его находить для миграций. Файлу БД в настройках проекта установить Build Action в None, а Copy To Output Directory — в Copy if newer. Тогда самая новая версия БД с миграциями будет попадать в bin при каждой сборке приложения.

Comment: Настройка copy if newer/копировать более позднюю версию решило проблему. После сборки изменения в файле базы данных копируются, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй путь к базе указать как указано здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli в разделе "Создание модели", указав фиксированное местоположение из Environment.